# what do i need to configure to route vrf to internet in a very simple way?

Tags: vrf

i designed a realy simple network.
i have a switch layer 3 with VRF named "A" with VLAN 1 forwarded to it.
the switch is connected to the internet with a router through gi0/3.
i want that computers in VRF A will be able to route to gi0/3 and also connect to the internet.

is there any simple way to do that?
also what do i need to config in the internet router?
i just want to mention that before i forwarded vlan 1 to VRF "A" everything worked fine and the computer was able to reach the internet.

[image: my network]

my switch config:

```
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
!
!
!
vtp domain CISCO-vIOS
vtp mode transparent
!
ip vrf A
!
!
!
ip name-server 8.8.8.8
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
vlan 100
 name VLAN100
!
vlan 200,300
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 media-type rj45
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 media-type rj45
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 media-type rj45
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 no switchport
 ip address 192.0.0.2 255.255.255.0
 negotiation auto
!
interface Vlan1
 ip vrf forwarding A
 ip address 172.20.20.254 255.255.255.0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.0.0.1
!
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
```

my router config:

```
hostname R1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
!
ip cef
ip name-server 8.8.8.8
!
!
ip auth-proxy max-nodata-conns 3
ip admission max-nodata-conns 3
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 mac-address f446.37b3.6672
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip forward-protocol nd
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.138
ip route 172.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 FastEthernet0/0
!
!
ip nat inside source list 1 interface FastEthernet0/1 overload
!
access-list 1 permit any
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put gi 0/3 in vrf A

```
Int gi 0/3
Vrf forwarding A
ip address 192.0.0.2 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: i can ping from the VRF to the internet, but i still can't from the computer.

Comment: i even added routing to the VRF "ip route vrf A 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.0.0.1" it didnt help

Comment: Can you ping from vlan 1?  Ping 1.1.1.1 source vlan1

Comment: thank you very much everyting is working. thank you!!

Comment: You’re welcome. Please consider describing what you changed/fixed. It will help others with similar problems.

Comment: Well i actually didnt do nothing, it was a problem with emulator software. I just restarted the computer.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of using VRF, it is necessary to use 'vrf' keywords in commands to specify what virtual routing table have to be used.

- ping vrf VRFNAME DESTINATION
- traceroute vrf VRFNAME DESTINATION